# Cordova.js file not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I use the following Cordova file in my jqm + phonegap application.

http://clubbedinapp.com/jsa/cordova.js

When the app opens, an alert comes up as follows:

[image]

Also, the page just freezes and doesn't allow me to anything.

How do I fix this error?

Some code from index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- The following must be AFTER jquery core and BEFORE jquery mobile js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true; // required
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none'; // optional - for better performance on Android
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true; // optional - added to show text message
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0; // optional added to remove sluggishness - jqm default 200
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.support.cors = true;
    });

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
// Do cool things here...
}

function getImage() {
// Retrieve image file location from specified source
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
alert('Get Picture Failed. Please Try Again.');
},{
quality: 50,
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}
);

}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=curClub+imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
params.clubID = curClub ;
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "url", win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) {
console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
console.log("Response = " + r.response);
console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);;
}

function fail(error) {
alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/latest.css"/>
<script src="js/latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So... are you trying to access a Cordova app in your browser without an emulator?

Comment: i just gave the screenshot via the browser, this problem occurs on my iPad also when I test the app

Comment: The problem is you're giving us few info. What's your code? Are you waiting for the ondeviceready event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to include the Cordova library **before** you use its API.

Based on the comments, you also have to NOT include the cordova.js file if you're using PhoneGap Build to create your installable files.

Comment: I have it if I am including the PhoneGap Build and the cordova.js file? right?

Comment: @nshah If you're using PhoneGap Build, the only thing you'll have is that the service will use the right version of Cordova for each Operating System.

Comment: My code worked fine for Android just like this.. However it is not working for ios though

Comment: Did you included the cordova.js file in your zip?

Comment: This is your error! You don't have to include it, just add a reference. Build will add it for you.

Comment: so you are saying that when i build it using phonegap on xcode, it has its own built in file called 'cordova.js'

Comment: will the file physically be shown there in the directory, or is it like a ghost

Comment: Mate, it seems you're a little bit confused. If you build using Xcode you've to include it. If you're using PhoneGap Build, you don't.

Comment: @nshah So why did you mentioned PhoneGap Build? I think you're messing up all the arguments and should read the documentation. If you've other questions, open another thread.